# Insert query inserting blank records to datebase

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm currently trying to use a separate class to handle all of my SQLite queries. The code below runs without any errors and creates a new row in the database, however the fields are empty. When the first messagebox shows it displays the strings text, when the second messagebox shows the command text the value string are empty. Can some one please point out what I've done wrong please.

Thanks in advance

```
public partial class v : Form
{
    DB db = new DB();

    public v()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db.journal = tbJournal.Text;
        db.selected = tbSelected.Text;
        db.job = tbJob.Text;
        db.note = tbNote.Text;

        db.insertToUser();
    }
}

public class DB
{
    static private string Journal, Selected, Job, Note, Date;
    public string journal { get { return Journal; } set { Journal = value; } }
    public string selected { get { return Selected; } set { Selected = value; } }
    public string job {  get { return Job; } set { Job = value; } }
    public string note { get { return Note; } set { Note = value; } }
    public string date { get { return Date; } set { Date = value; } }

    static private SQLiteConnection Con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = garden.db; version =3;");
    private SQLiteCommand cmdINSERT = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO User(Journal, Selected, Jobs, Notes, Date) VALUES('" + Journal + "','" + Selected + "','" + Job + "','" + Note + "','" + Date +"')",Con);


    public void insertToUser()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Journal + " " + Selected + " " + Job + " " + Note);
        Con.Open();
        MessageBox.Show(cmdINSERT.CommandText);

        try { cmdINSERT.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
        Con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing `cmdINSERT` inline, so it's building the command text with the property values when you construct the `DB` object (`new DB()`). At that point all the properties are empty. Just move `cmdINSERT` into the `insertToUser` method.

**Side note**

The `SQLiteConnection` type implements the `IDisposable` interface. Right now you're instantiating that object, but you're not closing the connection. To solve that, move that into `insertToUser` as well and wrap it in a `using` block:

```c#
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(...))
{
    // Create the command object
    // Execute query
}
```

That way the connection is properly closed and disposed of. You can find out more about `IDisposable` and `using` blocks here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects

Comment: Very similarly, it could be made a read only property instead of a field. e.g. `private SQLiteCommand cmdINSERT => ...`